# How can I add my stylesheets to the CSS editor in the WordPress backend?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom theme in WordPress, with its own set of stylesheets in a CSS directory. I want to be able to edit them through the WordPress backend (i.e. through Appearance>Editor).

I presume it will just be a couple of lines of code to add to `functions.php`, but I have searched around and can't find anything that will work out (I'm thinking because most of the solutions I've found are 4 years old...and WordPress has been updated a few times since then).

I tried adding filters and playing with `wp_enqueue_style` to no avail. Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1):

All files within your themes folder and sub-folders will be listed for editing under the theme editor.

I just checked under WordPress 3.8.1 and even files located under a sub-folder within my themes folder are all being listed.

Make sure there are no errors in your css files that prevent it from being opened in the theme editor.

Additionally, despite files located in sub-folders still being listed in the theme editor, for some reason the theme editor will not list css files in sub-folders. You will have to place your other css files in the root folder of your theme.

Move your css files to your themes root folder and you will be able to edit them in the WordPress theme editor.